# Add number of days of an existing days

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3

I have a problem and I don't understand where it is : 
So If I do :

```
$end_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+ $frequency days")); --> it works
```

If I do :

```
$end = $o_user->end;
$o_user->end  = date($end, strtotime("+ $frequency days")); ---> not work
```

I tested and the 2 dates have the format : `Y-m-d H:i:s`
Where is my error ? Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: what is value of "$o_user->end" @Harea Costicla

Comment: Once You use `$frequency` and once `$i_frequency`

Comment: `2016-05-23 10:48:42` @BrijalSavaliya

Comment: I edited question @nospor

Comment: What is the output of `$o_user->end` ?

Comment: if $o_user->end = '2016-05-23 10:48:42' then your function will treat as  date('2016-05-23 10:48:42', strtotime("+ $frequency days")); which is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Date's first param is the format, not an another date.

It should be something like this:

```
$o_user->end  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($end . " +$frequency days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to do

```
$o_user->end->modify("+ $frequency days");
```

It's even more readable and compact.

BTW your error is that `date()` function expect as first parameter a string (the date format)

Answer (score 0):

Change to `$o_user->end  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end, "+". $frequency. "days"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
$i_frequency = 4;
$end = '2016-05-23 10:48:42';
echo "==" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i_frequency days", strtotime($end)));
```

OR

```
$i_frequency = 4;
$end = '2016-05-23 10:48:42';
echo "==" . addDate($end, $i_frequency);
function addDate($date, $day)//add days
{
    $sum = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$date")) . " +$day days");
    $dateTo = date('Y-m-d', $sum);
    return $dateTo;
}
```